# Is it possible to use validation with express static routes?

Tags: node.js, validation, express, static

I'm using jwt token validation in my project to protect some importent data:

```
if (req.headers.auth) {
    var token = req.headers.auth.split(' ')[5];
    var payload = jwt.decode(token, 'blablabla...');

    if (!payload.sub) {
        res.status(401).send({
            message: 'Authentication failed'
        });
    }
    if (!req.headers.auth) {
        return res.status(301).send({
            message:'You are not authorized'
        });
    }
    res.send(data);
} else {
    res.header(404).send('Go away!');
}
```

Is it possible to use this method to protect the static rout, added using express static middleware?

UPDATE!!!
Ok, now jwt token validation set on my static route. But I have got another problem - how to send this token to node.js server BEFORE my angular app uploaded (beacose now it is blocked with new middleware) and started to insert tokens in to the http headers. Do I need some extra module, or maby my new middleware can request somehow  that jwt token from the browser?

Comment: ask your update in a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can attach an extra middleware to execute for your express static resources like this:

```
var staticMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Hello from staticMiddleware!');
    next();
};
app.use(staticMiddleware, express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Note that if you do add this JWT token checking middleware you should only be returning a response in this code (eg `res.send()`) if authentication fails. If the JWT is valid, to allow the code to proceed to the static route, call `next()`.

I would have two additional notes regarding your code:

1. Your `if(!req.headers.auth)` block will never be executed, you're already in side an `if(req.headers.auth)` block.
2. In all failure cases here (`req.headers.auth` is missing, or `payload.sub` is missing) you should return a `401 Unauthorized`. 301 and 404 would both be incorrect.

Comment: Sanks! I'll try it tommorow and do let you know how its works.

Comment: UPDATE!!!
Ok, now jwt token validation set on my static route. But I have got another problem - how to send this token to node.js server BEFORE my angular app uploaded (beacose now it is blocked with new middlevare) and started to insert tokens in to the http headers. Do I need some extra module, or maby my new middleware can request somehow  that jwt token from the browser?