# express static routes are not working when adding a validation middleware

Tags: javascript, express, validation, middleware, static-files

I am trying to add a validation middleware in order to protect my server data. When I get request (http://localhost:3000/filepath) the static route without the middleware:

```
app.use(express.static('data'));
```

I get a status 200 OK. But when I tried to get request the same route, but this time using a simple middleware as recommended in this other question ([Is it possible to use validation with express static routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005587/is-it-possible-to-use-validation-with-express-static-routes#_=_))

```
var staticMiddleware = function(req, res, next){
    console.log("middleware")
    next();
}

app.use(staticMiddleware, express.static('data'));
```

I`ve got a status 404 not found.

How can I add another middleware to app.use before the express.static middleware?

Comment: Your code is correct, you may use any number of middleware in `app.use`. If you are using the same code at the same position in the same file then this is strange, you may like to use `path.join()` for the static folder(`data` in your case) and also make folder path is correct

Comment: Lucas it seems that my answer was a bit misleading, it may have been the order of the middlewares, so can you try if  `app.use(express.static('data'), staticMiddleware);` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add them seperately.

```
app.use(express.static('data'));

var staticMiddleware = function(req, res, next){
    console.log("middleware")
    next();
}

app.use(staticMiddleware );
```

Comment: Why do you think that this is any better than `app.use(staticMiddleware, express.static('data'));`?  `app.use()` takes one or more middleware callback functions just fine.  This is from the [doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use): `app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])`.  They do not have to be added separately.

Comment: @jfriend00 I didn't know that, thanks for pointing. So you say the order matters here, right?  `app.use(express.static('data'), staticMiddleware);` also should have been worked, right?

Comment: Order matters only if one of them doesn't call `next()` or if one depends on the result of the other and thus has to be called first.